# Point position in a vector/array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm writing a C++ code that uses elements inside a vector / array. What I am doing is basically outside my main code I create a vector:

```
     const int Lx = 4, Ly = 4;
     const int L = Lx*Ly;

     inline void vector_lattice(){

         for (int i = 0; i < L+1; i++){
             s[i]=0.0;
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < L; i++){
             s[i] =1;
         }

    }
```

Lx and Ly will give me dimensions, since eventually I'll turn it into a 5x5 array.

In my problem this will give me a set of positions in "space", which should have an output that looks like

```
     .   .   .   .   .
     .   .   .   .   .
     .   .   .   .   .
     .   .   .   .   .
     .   .   .   .   .
```

However I now need something like

```
     .   .   .   .   .
       .   .   .   .   .
     .   .   .   .   .
       .   .   .   .   .
     .   .   .   .   .
```

Or be flexible to change those positions, but I don't really know how to do that since i can only be an integer and therefor my positions and spacemen's will be always the same. Does any one have any ideas on how that could be done?

Comment: The first loop will zero L+1 elements, is that intended?

Comment: Simply put "specimens" in even rows in even columns and odd rows in odd columns. Have a "specimen" that is an "empty specimen" to have blank values.

Comment: Without further constraints, what hinders you to interpret your array to be arranged like the second picture?

Answer (score 0):

Give it some abstraction. Define `Specimen` classes and store objects of these instead of `int`s or whatever you are using:

```
class Specimen {
    // Your Specimen class definition here, all specimens should inherit from it.
}

class EmptySpecimen : public Specimen {
    // Nothing here other than overriden virtual methods.
}

class SomeSpecimen : public Specimen {
    // Actual specimen implementation.
}
```

And then later in code you can initialize your vector using:

```
size_t width, height; // assign some values to these
vector< vector <Specimen*> > specimensMatrix;
specimensMatrix.resize(width);
for (size_t x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    specimensMatrix.resize(height);
}
```

To fill it how you expect it to be filled:

```
for (size_t x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    for (size_t y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            if (y % 2 == 0) {
                specimensMatrix[x][y] = new SomeSpecimen(/* ... */);
            else
                specimensMatrix[x][y] = new EmptySpecimen();
        }
        else {
            if (y % 2 == 0) {
                specimensMatrix[x][y] = new EmptySpecimen();
            else
                specimensMatrix[x][y] = new SomeSpecimen(/* ... */);
        }
    }
}
```

So your objects in matrix with size 8x6 will look like that (`E` for `EmptySpecimen` and `S` for `SomeSpecimen`):

```
SESESESE
ESESESES
SESESESE
ESESESES
SESESESE
ESESESES
```

Or, if you replace `E` with blank spaces and `S` with dots:

```
. . . . 
 . . . .
. . . . 
 . . . .
. . . . 
 . . . .
```